# Terraform: How can I configure the backend pool VM Scale Set in a second load balancer in an AKS Cluster

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-load-balancer

I have configured an AKS cluster through terraform. It deploys as standard an external load balancer configured with a backend pool pointing at the default pool's VM Scale Set.

I now would like to configure a second (internal) Load Balancer with a backend pool pointing at that same VM Scale Set. Is this possible? If so, how do I get a reference to that scale set? And how do I attach the load balancer to the scale set?

Config of the load balancer:

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "aks-internal-lb" {
  name                       = "${local.resource_prefix}-internal-lb"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  sku                        = "Standard"
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "InternalIPAddress"
    private_ip_address            = var.aks_internal_lb_ip
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    subnet_id                     = data.terraform_remote_state.net.outputs.aks_subnet_id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "aks-internal-lb-be-pool" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.aks-internal-lb.id
  name            = "InternalBackEndAddressPool"    
}
```

The corresponding aks config:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  name                       = "${local.resource_prefix}-k8s"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  dns_prefix                 = local.resource_prefix
  private_dns_zone_id        = "System"
  private_cluster_enabled    = true

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "defaultpool"
    node_count = 3
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2s_v3"
    vnet_subnet_id = data.terraform_remote_state.net.outputs.aks_subnet_id
    availability_zones    = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    max_pods              = 110
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of this LoadBalancer? Do you want to use it for the ingress-controller? If yes, you cant use na existing LB created with Terraform.

If you create a Service inside AKS it will automatically create an LoadBalancer for you in the Node Resource Group if you specify `type: LoadBalancer`:

External Load Balancer:

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 53.1.1.1
```

Internal Load Balancer:

```
metadata:
  name: internal-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    # If you use any different Subnet for the Ingress, add this:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "apps-subnet"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.240.0.25
```

Here is the documentation: [External-LB](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/load-balancer-standard.md) and [Internal-LB](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/internal-lb.md).

Comment: So, the use case is as follows:

Comment: I need:
1) an Ingress in k8s attached to an external load balancer which will be locked down to a range of IPs (For a third party to access our APIs).
2) an Ingress in k8s attached to an internal load balancer which will be accessible to users over a VPN (a back office application)
3)  These will have static IP addresses and domains configured in DNS.

Creating the AKS cluster as above provides either an internal or external load balancer depending on the config and private_cluster_enabled flag.

Comment: As I understand it, the Azure LB that is created will route traffic to aks, and hence to the ingresses at which point I can configure IP ranges and subdomain routing. What I'm unclear about is how to create a second Azure LB in terraform and attach it to the same scale set.

I did this manually previously to work out what I needed in terraform and it worked, but I may be missing something...

Comment: AFAIK "bring-your-own" LoadBalancer is not supported by AKS. Point 1 & 2 can be done via my examples above. The static IPs are configured via `loadBalancerIP`.

The Standard LoadBalancer created by AKS is used for egress. You can change that with `outbound_type = userDefinedRouting`. With this setting no LB is created in the node resource group and you can create a routing table for the egress traffic.

Comment: Just got back onto this, as I've been pulled onto some different work. Marked as correct answer, cheers.